# Detecting circular regions with OpenCV (with lot of small objects)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

In the original picture, I would like to detect circular regions. (glands) I managed to get to know the outlines of the regions, but because of the many smaller objects (nuclei), I can not go any further.

My original idea was to remove small objects using the **cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats** function. But unfortunately, as shown in the picture, the glandy regions also contain small objects, they are not connected properly. The function also throws out the small regions that outline the glands, leaving some parts out of the contours.

Can someone help me to find a solution to this problem? 
Thank you very much in advance

**Original picture**
[image: Original picture]

**The approximate contour of the glands (with a lot of small objects in it)**
[image: The approximate contour of the glands (with a lot of small objects in it)]

**After cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats**
[image: After cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats]

Comment: This is a hard problem, but fortunately it has been studied extensively. Please do a literature search before you try to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: I am aware of it, I read several scientific articles but unfortunately those methods doesn't work on my images. I will look for other solutions. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I don't think traditional image processing methods are able to deal with such a task. Sementatic segment in CNN (such as UNet )can do the job.

Answer (score 1):

## OpenCV

I think you can solve your task by using the [Hough transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html). Something like this could work for you (you have to adjust the parameters according to your needs):

```
import sys
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


def main(argv):
    filename = argv[0]
    src = cv.imread(filename, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
    if src is None:
        print ('Error opening image!')
        print ('Usage: hough_circle.py [image_name -- default ' + default_file + '] \n')
        return -1

    gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    gray = cv.medianBlur(gray, 5)

    rows = gray.shape[0]
    circles = cv.HoughCircles(gray, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, rows / 32,
                               param1=100, param2=30,
                               minRadius=20, maxRadius=200)

    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        for i in circles[0, :]:
            center = (i[0], i[1])
            # circle center
            cv.circle(src, center, 1, (0, 100, 100), 3)
            # circle outline
            radius = i[2]
            cv.circle(src, center, radius, (255, 0, 255), 2)


    cv.imshow("detected circles", src)
    cv.waitKey(0)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Some additional preprocessing might be required, to get rid of the noise, e.g. [Morphological Transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) and performing [edge detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d5c/tutorial_canny_detector.html) right before the transformation might be helpful as well.

---

## Neural Networks

Another option would be to use a neural network for image segmentation. A quite successful one is `Mask RCNN`. There is already a working python implementation on GitHub: [Mask RCNN - Nucleus](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/samples/nucleus/inspect_nucleus_model.ipynb).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I will definiately try this method :)